# How to get flexbox items to be aware of their contents?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a project that has divs that will contain unknown content, some maybe fixed size, some maybe inline-blocks, some may have width of 100%.  I'm using flex-box on the container since I want the contents to be vertically aligned.

In the following example I have holder which is a flex box and differing numbers of .item columns, within these columns will be component of unknown size, in the first holder it has one item that contains something with width of 100%, I want this to take up 100% of the holder.

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="full">Data</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this example I have 3 items, the first 2 should take up the space they require and the 3rd item should take up the remaining space since it's width is 100%, is there anyway of doing this either with flexbox or some other method that will keep the contents vertically centrally aligned?

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="item">
        <div>Data 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="full">Data 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS I'm using, again if there is another way of doing this without flex I don't mind.

```
.holder {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-end;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.holder .item {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.holder .full {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.holder {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-end;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.holder .item {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.holder .full {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    <div class="item">
        <div>Data 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="full">Data 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's what I'm trying to achieve, these properties are built up of variable number of components, some maybe 100% which need to take up remaining space or share it between other 100% items, some are fixed size, some are auto.  But as you can see the first two items are not stretching to the size of the container.

[image: Properties popup]

Full control HTML as requested, "displayControl" draws the actual controls but this top level control is unaware of what they are drawing, although it now has the field entry.propertySpacer, as suggested, to force a flex-grow, which seems to work.

```
<div *ngIf="control && intControls.length > 0" class="container">
        <div *ngFor="let intControl of intControls" class="property">
            <div *ngIf="intControl.property && intControl.property.displayName !== false" class="label">
                {{intControl.property.displayName === true ? intControl.property.name : intControl.property.displayName}}
            </div>
            <div class="propertyEntry">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let entry of intControl.controls">
                    <div *ngIf="entry.canConnect && entry.dataValue" class="propitem proplabel" [title]="entry.dataName">
                        {{entry.dataName}}
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="!entry.canConnect || !entry.dataValue" class="propitem" [ngClass]="{flexgrow : entry.propertySpacer}">
                        <displayControl [control]="entry" [fireEvents]="false" [editing]="false"></displayControl>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="entry.canConnect" class="propitem" (keydown)="clickDataSet($event, intControl, entry)" (click)="openDataSet(intControl, entry)">
                        <div class="icon grey" [ngClass]="{'blue' : entry.dataValue}" [title]="entry.dataValue ? entry.dataName : 'Databind'" tabindex="0">
                            <mat-icon fontIcon="commit"></mat-icon>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ng-container>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) selector:

```css
.holder {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.holder .item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.item:has(.full) {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="item">
    <div>Data 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Data 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="full">Data 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I’m using embedded components in each of the .item divs so will be unaware of their contents, as such I won’t be able to determine if   the components have 100% styles or classes.

Answer (score 0):

Since, it is a flex item simply use `flex: 1` to take the remaining space.

```
.holder .item:last-child{
    flex: 1;
}
```

```css
.holder {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-end;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.holder .item {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.holder .item:last-child{
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    <div class="item">
        <div>Data 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="full">Data 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I’m using embedded components in each of the .item divs so will be unaware of their contents, as such I won’t be able to determine if   the components have 100% styles or classes.

Comment: Even if you are unware about the contents inside of the `.item` class it will still work because `.holder .full {width: 100%;}` is not necessary. Still the last `.item` will take the remaining space. And if you can't even assign the `.item` class in your embedded codes then you can try this: `.holder div:last-child{flex: 1;}`. It will work for the last div.

Comment: Again it won’t work, it could be the second column that could be 100% or the first or a 4th column so :last-child is ineffectual as again the content will be unknown.

Comment: It wasn't clear in your question. OK, then I think you have to find any information/pattern that makes that particular `.item` different from the others. There must be something which can be used.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the top level component will be unaware of what’s going in there, I tried with TABLE as well but the columns where still overly padded for the content.  Just surprised there doesn’t seem to be a formatting solution that “Just works”

Comment: Does this particular `.item` contains a child div with the class `.full` always? Or it's child div has any property or pattern that is different from other `.item div`s?

Comment: the .full is just an example that tries to force 100%, the actual components I don't know anything about, it may have a style that is set to 100% or a class that is 100%.  I've had to go with your suggestion of forcing a "IsStretched" property if the control creator want to push the size of the control to take up the space.  Not ideal but looks like the only way around it.  Not sure how I can mark that comment as the answer but I've upvoted it so maybe the mods can mark it.

Comment: Is it possible to inspect that app/program generated html in browser ? Even a screenshot could be enough to solve it. And a comment can not be marked as answer but you did mark it as useful comment :)

Comment: Added code in main content

Comment: Glad to know you fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to cover remaining space by uing **flex 1 1;** property of flex inside your child.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).